# OpenCV for delphi 7, issue with the library wrapper

Tags: delphi, image-processing, delphi-7, pattern-recognition

I would like to use the library in my D7 project.
I have downloaded the wrappers from: 
[sourceforge.net](http://opencv-delphi.svn.sourceforge.net)

The problem is that the example the author wrote to recognize squares in the given image doesn't work. After some time it raises AV exception from the method:

```
function cvContourPerimeter(contour: PCvSeq): double;
begin
  result := cvArcLength(contour,CV_WHOLE_SEQ,1);
end;
```

Also the method: cvArcLength was put in try except block which seems to be that the problem 
wasn't solved.

Does anyone have an experience with OpenCV and D7 or maybe have other wrappers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I have migrated to the newest version of OpenCV.